# Не могу понять ошибку: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php

Здравствуйте помогите исправить, спасибо заранее.

Содержимое файла:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "***";
$dbuser = "***";
$dbpass = "***";
$dbname = "***";
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Ошибка базы данных: " . mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Ошибка базы данных: " . mysql_error());
?>

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111 "Connection refused") in /var/www/bajex3/data/www/moyki.red-shadow.ru/engine/data/db.php on line 6
    Ошибка базы данных: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
```

Comment: @bajex, слова

      Connection refused

однозначно сообщают, что этот сокет (`var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`) **никто не слушает** (другими словами -- сервер MySQL с ним не запущен).

Answer (score 2):

Вместо домена используйте IP или наоборот, и переходите на PDO ИЛИ Mysqli

**Обновление**

По mysqli не нашел, [по PDO](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1463), ответ на ваш вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240287/ubuntu-11-04-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysq), по PDO кстати есть мануал и на [хэшкоде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/302421/php-pdo-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85).

Comment: Мануал можно по mysqli ? и там прописанно localhost.

Comment: > По mysqli не нашел

(тут я сдерживаю уничижителные высказываения в матерной форме) 
это что вообще значит ? мануалы на php.net ...

Comment: вы вообще, Люди **для вас** пишут доходчивую документацию, все разжевывают, кто-то комментирует примерами, переводит на русский язык, всё это лежит на официальном сайте, а вы всё на вторичных источниках ищите документацию.

Comment: @eicto спасибо, кэп (с), если человек использует старый API, то скорее всего в документации на php.net он не разберется, а простых примеров по MySQLi я в гугле не нашел.